# Como mostrar en lista una consulta en PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es que quiero mostrar el detalle de un producto en formato lista haciendo una consulta PHP a mi BD.

```
<div class="col-md-6 descripcion">
     <ul>
         <?php echo $producto->descSofas ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Cuéntanos algo más, ¿no? Donde guardas ese detalle, formato de la tabla, sistema gestor de la base de datos, ...

Comment: Por favor coloca el error que te está mostrando.

Comment: Antes de intentar salida PHP al navegador, debes aprender nociones básicas de html: [especificacion ul/li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), y se incluyen ejemplos.

Comment: Por favor, has el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Aquí no resolvemos tareas escolares, aquí ayudamos con problemas específicos. Saludos!